# Android Diplay Fragment below Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am new to Android and learning how to use fragments.
I came across this question I have an `EditText` and a `Button` in an Activity.

On a button click, I want to display the content of a EditText in the `TextView` which is part of the Fragment. So my layout should be the `EditText`, `Button` and below that the `TextView`.

My code is working but I am not able to display the `TextView` below the button and it is appearing in the top of the screen.

Main Activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.dhaval.fragmentassignment6a.MainActivity">


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"

        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:singleLine="false" />

    <Button
        android:text="Submit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@id/fragmentSingle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        tools:layout_marginTop="150sp">

    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment xml:

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.dhaval.fragmentassignment6a.SimpleAddition">

        <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@id/textView12"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

    </FrameLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        edittext=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("edittext1", String.valueOf(edittext.getText()));
                FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                SimpleAddition simpleAddition=new SimpleAddition();
                simpleAddition.setArguments(bundle);
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentSingle,simpleAddition,"bottom");
                fragmentTransaction.commit();

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Show what you tried

Comment: pls check the code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your MainActivity.xml and fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:singleLine="false" />

<Button
    android:text="Submit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragmentSingle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  <----made changes here---->
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"     
    >

   </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="---same of yours-----">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    <''''done changes here''''''>
    android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment"
    android:id="@+id/tv"/>
```

Fragment.xml

Comment: I hope you understand the problem. that match_parent tag was taking the entire display area of an activity.

Comment: thanks for the solution.It worked for me.But now the result is appearing at the bottom of the screen.i tried aligning the framelayout but no success.I want the output exactly after button

Comment: @APPYSHAH  You added a tag 'android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" in frameLayout, ' so the fragment added at the bottom of layout. if you want just below the button remove this tag from and add         'android:layout_below="@+id/button"  ' in frame layout this will resolve ur problem